# Unable to start the Windows Phone Emulator on Visual Studio 2015 and Surface Pro 4

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8-emulator, hypervisor

I am running on 
 * Visual Studio 2015
 * Windows Surface Pro 4

When I attempt to load a Windows Phone application, I get the message, "Unable to start the Windows Phone Emulator. Windows Phone Emulator is unable to start because the hypervisor is not running. The likely cuase is that hardware-assisted virtualization is not enabled."

I've searched on SO and done the following checks

- make sure to use turn on/off windows features to turn on hypervisor
- gone into the bios to enable VT-x (actually, the BIOS in windows surface pro 4 doesn't even have this option to enable or disable)
- enabled data execution prevention

One thing I've noticed is that when I go to Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools, I do not see the Hypervisor-V Manager shortcut. Also, when I type in "hypvervisor-v" into the searchbox, there are no local hits.

Also, I am running VirutalBox on my system, and I am wondering if this is causing a conflict?

Any ideas if there is a problem with Windows Phone development on a Surface Pro 4? Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes its possible. Have you added Hyper-V in the add windows features? I dont think its on by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this the link to...

http://www.infoworld.com/article/2998538/microsoft-windows/surface-book-and-surface-pro-4-problems-proliferate.html

> You have to manually turn on Hyper-V in any Windows 10 Pro system;
>   it's not turned on by default

Comment: Installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 seemed to turn it on for me by default.